# error when integrating with XMPP into my application

Tags: iphone, xmpp

When I am integrating XMPP into my application into my app I am getting an error. Please help me in solving this problem:

```
Build CheckOut of project CheckOut with configuration Debug

Ld build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CheckOut.app/CheckOut normal i386
cd "/Users/stellentmac1/Desktop/CheckOut 2"
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk "-L/Users/stellentmac1/Desktop/CheckOut 2/build/Debug-iphonesimulator" "-L/Users/stellentmac1/Desktop/CheckOut 2/../../../../../xmppframework/Vendor/libidn" "-L/Users/stellentmac1/Desktop/CheckOut 2" "-F/Users/stellentmac1/Desktop/CheckOut 2/build/Debug-iphonesimulator" -filelist "/Users/stellentmac1/Desktop/CheckOut 2/build/CheckOut.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CheckOut.build/Objects-normal/i386/CheckOut.LinkFileList" -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -lxml2 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework CFNetwork -framework MobileCoreServices -framework SystemConfiguration -lz.1.2.3 -lresolv -o "/Users/stellentmac1/Desktop/CheckOut 2/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CheckOut.app/CheckOut"

ld: warning: directory '/Users/stellentmac1/Desktop/CheckOut 2/../../../../../xmppframework/Vendor/libidn' following -L not found
ld: duplicate symbol _kRFSRVResolverErrorDomain in /Users/stellentmac1/Desktop/CheckOut 2/build/CheckOut.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CheckOut.build/Objects-normal/i386/RFSRVResolver-1A90E36B7A8C9E67.o and /Users/stellentmac1/Desktop/CheckOut 2/build/CheckOut.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CheckOut.build/Objects-normal/i386/RFSRVResolver-7299ADCEDF231192.o
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a linking problem caused by a less-than careful use of the framework.

Do you have a copy of the xmppframework linked *and* the sources included in your project, or two copies of the sources included in your project?